# Are there any ways to mitigate or workaround mutably capturing the environment in a closure used in a loop?

Tags: rust

The `check_vec()` closure captures a mutable reference to the `values` vector. The compiler is not smart enough to understand that `values.push(0xbeef)` call is safe. I have tried compiling using NLL feature flag, but that didn't help either.

```
fn main() {
    let mut values = Vec::with_capacity(16);

    let mut check_vec = || {
        if values.len() < 16 {
            values.push(0xdead);
        }
    };

    for _ in 0..32 {
        check_vec();
        values.push(0xbeef);
    }

    check_vec();
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a153790b69b579af80f5c9c81b1aac26&version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015))

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `values` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:12:9
   |
4  |     let mut check_vec = || {
   |                         -- first mutable borrow occurs here
5  |         if values.len() < 16 {
   |            ------ previous borrow occurs due to use of `values` in closure
...
12 |         values.push(0xbeef);
   |         ^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
...
16 | }
   | - first borrow ends here
```

Are there any ways to mitigate or workaround this limitation?

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [Can't borrow mutably within two different closures in the same scope](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49703990/155423) and/or [Problems with mutability in a closure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41990175/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: TL;DR the duplicates: pass an argument or switch to `RefCell`.

Comment: `RefCell` introduces runtime overhead, which I would prefer to avoid. I was hoping for a solution which can make compiler "happy". Thanks anyways.

Comment: The solution to make the compiler happy is to pass `values` as an argument as @Shepmaster said.

Comment: @mcarton that diminishes the value of capturing environment :shrug:

Comment: In your example, it is trivial to use a parameter. In a non-trivial example, how would you expect the borrow checker to verify that what you are doing is safe? Generally, capturing the environment is still very useful for immutable closures.

Comment: @mcarton how do you feel about [my addition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49703990/cant-borrow-mutably-within-two-different-closures-in-the-same-scope) of "Unsafe programmer-brain-time borrow checking"?

Comment: @Shepmaster Good!

Comment: @ArazAbishov I've added an unsafe version to [Can't borrow mutably within two different closures in the same scope](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49703990/155423) to address your concern.